# Visual Studio Code sidebar lower terminal minimum width

Tags: visual-studio-code

Using Visual Studio Code now, I have the terminal open to the right. I used to be able to drag to resize the column to be very small, but now it seems like there's a minimum width it has to be before it snaps from being open to closed.

How can I fix that and get it back to being fully resizable?

I tried resizing it, expected it to resize, and it closed instead.